# How dot notation works in functional component of React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

While I was searching article about compound component pattern, I have found out that accessing sub-component through dot notation is possible like javascript object.

How this is possible and how it works? does this work because component is also object of javascript?

```
const App = () => (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>Home</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Blog</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>About</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
```

Comment: You could answer this yourself by going through the source code of your Menu component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is accomplished my simply attaching the compound component as a property to the parent component.

Attaching is how you keep the nested compound component with its parent component. The alternative is to export `Item` separately, and then also import it separately. In many cases the nested child component is ***only valid*** as a direct descendent of the parent component, consuming a context, or being informed how to "layout" in the DOM.

Example:

```
const Menu = () => <div>Menu Component</div>
const Item = () => <div>Item Component</div>

Menu.Item = Item;

export default Menu;
```

Usage:

```
import Menu from '../path/to/menu';

const App = () => (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>Home</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Blog</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>About</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-dot-notation-works-in-functional-component-of-react-js]

Demo Code:

```
const Menu = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Menu Component</h1>
    {children}
  </div>
);
const Item = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;

Menu.Item = Item;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Menu>
        <Menu.Item>Home</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item>Blog</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item>About</Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

## Question

> Does this work because component is also object of javascript?

No, not objects, but functional components (and class-based components) are transpiled into a regular javascript function invoked by the React framework, and as a variable reference you can attach properties to them.

Comment: @GoonGamja Added a bit of context around "attaching", hopefully that clears up your follow-on query.